# JMeter - Determining Concurrent users, Test duration for a load test in preparation for a peak day event

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a requirement for a performance load test.
Expected no of visits in a day - 200,000
peak duration per day - 10 hrs
average session duration - 10 mins

- what would be my no of concurrent users for a 1 hr load test or 15 mins load test.
- and should I run the test for 15 mins instead of an hr.
- a throughput of 5.75tps was given too, should I include this in my test plan or allow the load test to determine the application throughput.

Comment: I meant no of visits = 200,000,
peak duration hrs = 10hrs,
average session duration = 10 mins

My calculation gives me 3,333 concurrent users for an 1hr or 833 conc users for 15 mins. what would be the best approach?
and should I leave the loop count set to 0 or 1  or I should l should set it to infinite? I would appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

- > what would be my no of concurrent users for a 1 hr load test or 15 mins load test.

  given your "Expected no of visits in a day - 200,000" the number of visits per hour will be 200000/24 ~= 8333 and in 15 minutes ~= 2083
- > and should I run the test for 15 mins instead of an hr.

  I would consider 15 minutes test as a [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) and 1 hour test as a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Soak_testing)
- > a throughput of 5.75tps was given too, should I include this in my test plan or allow the load test to determine the application throughput.

  again it depends on the performance test type you're running, if you're replicating a specific load pattern to see if new system under test version performance is the same or better than the previous - you can limit JMeter's throughput to the given value and focus on response time instead. If you're running a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) just make sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and your workload model reflects the behaviour of the real user and start increasing the load until you reach the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and identify the first [bottleneck](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks).

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, it makes better sense now. 
Also, do I leave the loop count set to 0 (or 1) or I leave it set to infinite during the duration of the test?